# Using isolated gate driver for switching loads sans MOSFET

Tags: digital-logic, gate-driving, isolated

I am trying to simplify my circuit and use a single multi channel part for both driving high current MOSFETs and directly driving a much smaller inductive load without a MOSFET basically as a digital isolator.

Can I do that?

This is the part I am using [ADUM3220](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/ADUM3220WARZ-RL7/3820069)

The circuit is basically Out1 to 20A MOSFET, Out2 2.5A inductive load.
Added a simplified schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpzQ0c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Sure, it's possible. I've done that but, the devil is in the detail and you have provided no detail.

Comment: what's the multi-channel part you have ?

Comment: Depends. MOSFET drivers are usually made for very high current for a very short amount of time, then just clamp the voltage there until next switch cycle. If your continuous current is high, it may overheat. Please show with a schematic what you are proposing.

Comment: The part I am using is:  ADUM3220WARZ
https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/ADUM3220WARZ-RL7/3820069
Circuit is basically Out1 to 20A mosfet/ Out2 2.5A inductive load

With output A connected directly to mosfet

Comment: Please add details to question. Please also add adiagrsm- it's easy for apparently clear description to miss key points. Inbuilt diagram Tool is quite intuitive.. check ic dissipation at 2.5A

Comment: Datasheet says max 3 ohm internal output resistance for your driver. Dissipation at a constant 2.5A current would be excessive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, you can't use that chip for the 2.5A digital isolation inductor.

Long answer: Unless you respect an ON time around 1µs (short circuit condition) and keep the average current of that channel less than the "Average Output Current per Pin (IO)" under absolute maximum rating (which mean a small duty cycle,) then you might get away with it.

But the question that rises, why do you want to drive it directly? You can either use another Mosfet or a high power optocoupler.

Comment: Thanks. After looking at all the comments it makes complete sense. I will use another mosfet.